# VS2010 extension for formatting C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a Visual Studio Extension. That extension, whenever ran by the user will primarily format/indent C# code in a defined manner. For example

```
private void Method(int a, int b)
{
}
```

will be converted to something like

```
private void Method
(
int a,
int b
)
    {
    }
```

At this point I have no experience or idea about the APIs that I can use for this kind of task. I would like to know if there are any APIs that MS provides for parsing C# code in a .cs file or any third party APIs? or any general APIs that can help me in achieving this kind of thing.

Comment: Tip: I think that `astyle` ([Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)) is flexible enough to do the formatting work.

Comment: out of curiosity, for what reason? I know it is subjective, but to me that is a very ugly/hard-to-read layout...

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: lol i know.. but my organization don't know this and I am definitely not in the position of arguing about it..

Comment: try telling your organization that VS does a lot of automatic formatting already, and that you can customize it to some extent only with the built-in options. It's not exactly what you want, but you won't have to waste one developer's time to do code formatting, and it comes with VS at no additional cost - that should be understandable by everyone :)

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco: Actually I just wanted to make a utility for myself which will traverse the code once I am done with it in order to make sure if there is something which is not according to the defined guideline, make that right. Yes, you are right about the built-in formatting customization options, but there are still some deficiencies in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CodeElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeelement%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) interface (have a look at this example: [HOWTO: Navigate the code elements of a file from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006008.aspx)). With that you will be able to get information about methods, for example, but I do not know if that allows you to go beyond that level.

If that's not enough for you, [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) comes with a C# grammar in the examples.